# Prestashop module development - How can I call a controller initMethod at module installation?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In controllers/front I created a controller named abandonedCarts:

```
class <moduleName>AbandonedCartsModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    $this->store_debug('Controller - __construct');
}


public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();
    $this->store_debug('Controller - init');
}

}
```

where store_debug is a function that simply logs on the db something (just for check).
Thanks to this I know that when I call the controller from URL in this way

```
site/index.php?fc=module&module=olyo&controller=abandonedCarts
```

the construct and init methods are being called, but what I need is the controller being called when the module is installed (or at its first start).

In the main file I also put in the constructor this line:

```
$this->controllers = array('abandonedCarts');
```

But I'm not sure I even need it

Comment: Which version of prestashop?

Comment: Why do you need to call the init method on module install ?

Comment: @sarcom The version is 1.6

Comment: @shagshag Read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181893/ecommerce-plugin-development-how-to-periodically-check-the-platform-db-and-cal/47191574?noredirect=1#comment81346672_47191574

Answer (score 1):

You can include the Controller and just call the object method like following :

```
<?php 
class MyModule extends Module {

  public install(){
     $file = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/'.$this->name.'/controllers/front/default.php';
     require_once $file;
     $obj = new ObjectController();
     $obj->my_super_method();
     return true;
  }
}
```

You don't need the controller parameter. You shall stick to what is include by default with Prestashop's Generator here : https://validator.prestashop.com/

Comment: Instantiate and call initContent of a FrontController in the back office may have side effects. For exemple hook DisplayHeader will be called https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1328a2876a955eab1a4edd34c4976eb36a8983db/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L532

Comment: Why don't you just directly use another sub function which encapsulate what you want and bring it inside controller and module installation ?

Comment: @MattLoye I tried your solution, but something strange happens: in the module install() method I simply instantiated the controller without calling any method, while in the controller I'm doing nothing, but as soon as I install the module from the back office it redirect me on the shop site

Comment: @MattLoye  Also I'm not sure I understood your last suggestion, but I guess I can't because it's not compliant with MVC pattern

Comment: @frabis that's the side effects I was talking about, FrontController should not be instantiated in admin.

Comment: Simply create a method from your module and when you need it in a controller just instanciate the module in the controller to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not instantiate a FrontController in admin context, here is a workaround :

Your module :

```
<?php 
class MyModule extends Module {
  public install(){
     $result = parent::install();
     if ($result) {
         $this->doStuff();
     }
     return $result;
  }

  public function doStuff() {
     // do stuff
  }
}
```

your controller

```
<?php
class <moduleName>AbandonedCartsModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->module->doStuff();
    }
}
```